# ClipIt: how to use actions?

Tags: unity

I have ClipIt 1.4.2 and in the preferences, I can define actions, but I have no idea how to use them. It talks about clicking on the ClipIt icon with control key pressed, but if I click on the icon (in the top of the screen) with control key or without does not make a difference.

(ubuntu 16.04 with unity)

Comment: The action selection menu will pop up when you press the hotkey that you can configure in the preferences. Normally it's `Control+Shift+a`.

Answer (score 5):

In ClipIt preferences you can define your own actions (in "Actions" tab). Everything you define in "Command" section of an action is executed in system.

For example if you define action:

Action: `popup`

Command: `zenity --info --text "%s"`

On action execution you should get popup with your text from clipboard (if zenity is installed in your system, which is installed by default in Ubuntu now).

Other example:

Action: `add_texts`

Command: `clipit "text before %s text after"`

It will copy to your clipboard actual clipboard content enclosed with "text before" and "text after" texts.

Answer (score 1):

A really fast way to get acquainted with clipit is to just see what documentation it brings:

```
man clipit
```

but one way you can get started is to acctually start the program:

```
clipit &
```

then you will notice a new icon in your tray (left most icon):

[image]

if you now Right-Click on it you will see the Preferences Item, from there you can customize the program to your needs, it works the way you tell it to.

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP says that clicking the ClipIt icon *with control key or without does not make a difference*. This is what needs an answer.

Comment: I answerd by explaing that a RIGHT CLICK on the icon is necessary to bring up the MENU where the PREFERENCES reside. That is where the OP will find what is currently set and eventually make changes to his liking i.e: CTRL + Click.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I expected long ago. It took me some time to figure this out (pipe):

Action to copy some text to the clipboard:
echo "some text" | clipit

Action to copy the result of a command, in this case, date, to the clipboard:
echo `date +%%F` | clipit