# How to create "static items" in clipit?

Tags: clipboard, clipboard-manager

There are a few  [Q&As](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=clipit+is%3Aq) about [clipit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clipit/) on this site, but information about *how* to use some of its features remains elusive.

The documentation speaks of being able to maintain and use a list of "static items", but I cannot work out **how to create the static items** themselves. (Perhaps this is related to a previous question -- lacking a useful answer -- about [how to use "actions"](https://askubuntu.com/q/809026/38585) in clipit.)

If someone has worked this out, it would be good to know. (I'm on 16.04 LTS, FWIW.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click the Clipit icon in the toolbar and select *Manage History*. A pop-up will appear titled Manage History.

Then choose the copied item from the list in the pop-up that you want to make static and click the *Edit* button at the bottom. Another pop-up will appear titled Editing Clipboard.

At the bottom left there will be a check box to make the item static, then click the OK button and that's it.

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a hotkey to access static items by number in the history dropdown? They also have index, but there isn't any way to trigger it seemingly.