# ClipIt: I can't access Preferences

Tags: 18.04

According to [ClipIt: how to use actions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809026/clipit-how-to-use-actions) : 
If you Right-Click on the ClipIt icon you will see the Preferences Item. 
But that is not true! At least not on my Ubuntu 18.04. I get a list of clips whether I right-click or left-click. 
I also asked the question on https://sourceforge.net/p/gtkclipit/support-requests/4/ but nobody has answered.

Answer (score 2):

I also use Ubuntu 18.04 and ClipIt. At first i did config too many history items, and then indeed i had the same problem : at the bottom of the ClipIt list are 5 menu items (in order top to bottom) : Offline mode, About, Manage history, Preferences and Quit .. but they were not visible due to the config .. so i edit the file /home/$USER/.config/clipit/clipitrc and i changed items_menu=# to a lower number (mine is 18 max now, due to screen resolution and font size). If this was your problem, then here's how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks! That was probably the problem, but luckily I now use Clipboard Indicator instead. It doesn't have the problems that many other clipboard managers have in my experience. It has a max. of 50 history items. That is my setting.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with VMWare + Linux.  I installed/updated vmtoolkits etc. Finally got the answer.

Troubleshooting:

1. Select some text (in browse, text file etc).
2. Press Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V consequently very quickly. (In less than 1 second)
3. If the text get pasted, the problem is with the purging time of the OS.

Goto Preferences > History tab >

a) Deselect "Purge history after timeout"

OR

b) Put a larger value like 10 seconds for "Purge history after timeout"

[image]